# Does React Table Support Icons in Cells, and Collapsible Rows

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Can [React-Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqqdm.png) support  (Please refer to the image below)

1. icon in table - in green rectangle ;
2. collapse row when necessary - in red rectangle?

If yes, may I know example on how to do it?
If not is there a react table library that can support this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can define your custom cell following this:
   [React data table custom cells](https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/story/columns-cells-custom-cells--custom-cells)

Example:

```
const columns = [
        {
            name: 'Skill',
            selector: row => row.skill,
            sortable: true,
            reorder: true,
            allowRowEvents: true,
            cell: (row) => {
                return (
                    <div className="my-skill-component-column">
                        <img height="24px" width="24px" alt={row.skill} src={"/Course Assign_Color.png"} />
                        <div>{row.skill}</div>
                    </div>);
            }
            ,
        }
]
```

Result:
[image]

2. Here is an example provided: [React custom expand](https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/story/expandable-basic--basic)